# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - separate configurations for different environments

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Amazon Web Services (AWS) Elastic Beanstalk for hosting my Django/Python web application. I have two environments created in Beanstalk - `production` and `acceptance` (staging).
My web app source code is in version control in git. Deployment config files are located in the `.ebextensions` directory at the root of git repository, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html).

I have 2 separate Django config files for my application: `conf/acceptance.py` and `conf/production.py`.

How do I set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_CONFIG` environment variable separately for each environment?

I have tried editing it in beanstalk web ui, but it is resets when I redeploy. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same setup for one of my own apps. I'm using the **Configuration** > **Software Configuration** > **Environment Properties** section on the Beanstalk UI to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` as `app.settings.production` or `app.settings.staging` depending on the environment. This would likely be `app.conf.production` and `app.conf.acceptance` for you.

Could it be that one of your `.ebxtensions` files has an `options_setting` variable that is overriding this during deploy?

Answer (score 1):

To set a different value for each environment, you would need to create 2 env config files files for each environment in you .ebextensions folder, then pick ONLY the right one depending on where you deploy. This way your environment property `DJANGO_SETTINGS_CONFIG` would automatically be set during deployment and you won't need to change it in the web ui anymore.

## Example:

Deploy this in acceptance environment:

*env-config-acceptance.config*

```yaml
option_settings:
    - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_CONFIG
      value: config.value.acceptance
```

Deploy this in production environment:

*env-config-production.config*

```yaml
option_settings:
    - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_CONFIG
      value: config.value.production
```

Comment: Is it possible to set specific config file when `eb deploy` command?